# Does X11 actually have a native fullscreen mode?

Tags: linux, gpu, xorg, gaming, opengl

I'm writing some OpenGL graphics demos on a Linux-based system, and from what I can gather the X server doesn't seem to actually have a native fullscreen mode as you'd expect with games, etc. From what I understand, X is always just "windows." Therefore, it would seem "fullscreen" on X just means "fullscreen borderless window" in Windows PC terms. The graphics driver, I assume, just detects the window is converting the entire screen and sets itself appropriately.
Am I completely wrong here? Or is everything literally just a window?

Answer (score 1):

The old post of
[X11/GLX - Fullscreen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065669/x11-glx-fullscreen-mode)
has some useful data on the subject.

The best (but not most upvoted)
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28396773/165358)
for me contains the following code:

```
Atom wm_state   = XInternAtom (display, "_NET_WM_STATE", true );
Atom wm_fullscreen = XInternAtom (display, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN", true );

XChangeProperty(display, window, wm_state, XA_ATOM, 32,
                PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *)&wm_fullscreen, 1);
```

Which is further described in
[Extended Window Manager Hints](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2731936):

> _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN indicates that the window should fill the entire screen and have no window decorations. Additionally the Window Manager is responsible for restoring the original geometry after a switch from fullscreen back to normal window. For example, a presentation program would use this hint.

That's the situation at the moment, which is not perfect.
The
[Proposal To Fix The Full-Screen Linux Window Mess](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTIxNDg)
does not seem to have been implemented.

Comment: Well there it is, I guess. It would seem then that the current state is just "fullscreen window," if you opt not to bypass the window manager (which is risky if you expect your native Linux app to run on Chromebooks, as an example).

Comment: The `window` is called root. See `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_window`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen X11 app go fullscreen and change the pixel resolution. but variable resolution monitors are less popular theses days. LCDs and OLEDs have hard pixels unlike the soft-pixels CRTs had.

Still there's an XRANDR (or something) call that can get a list of available resolutions. Expect it to be short.

Comment: I understand the resolution can be changed, but that's a separate issue from how the X server actually produces images on the screen. xrandr will show specs about the video card/display so you know what modes are supported, but what I'm actually interested in is the "fullscreen" part: is there actually any difference between "fullscreen" and "borderless window?"